# Case 0 in Switch Statement

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

I was using the switch statement in C# and I realised, though the variable passed in the switch statement is an enum, the switch statement does not throw an error for case 0, but does throw an error for case 1,2,3...
I was wondering why is it so.
I know how to use enums with the switch case and I don't need help with that,  I want to know why isn't it throwing an error with 0. Since 0 is an integer.

Here is the code, and this compiles without any errors.
MathOperator is an enum.

```
 public double Test5(double num1, double num2, MathOperator op)
    {
        double answer=0;
        switch (op)
        {

            case 0:
                {
                    break;
                }

        }
        return answer;
    }
```

Thank you for answering my question!

Comment: instead of using 0,1,2,3,..., try to use the enum name in your case

Comment: You should include the error and the declaration of `MathOperator` since they are both clearly relevant.  And what @lamandy said :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a rule in the C# specification chapter 13 "Conversions":

> 13.1.3 Implicit enumeration conversions
>   An implicit enumeration conversion permits the decimal-integer-literal 0 to be converted to any enum-type.

So 0 is special here in a way that no other integer literal is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need a default case to handle all other `MathOperator` that is passed into the method `Test5` that is currently not in your `switch` statement, which I think is the issue in your case. A rule of thumb would be to have a switch case that checks against all `enum` members listed in your `enum`.

```
 public double Test5(double num1, double num2, MathOperator op)
 {
    double answer=0;
    switch (op)
    {
        // Use it like this.
        case MathOperator.YourOperator:
        {
            break;
        }
        case MathOperator.Multiply:
        {
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            // Other cases
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question as to why `0` is allowed, but the others aren't.  Can't find the part of the spec that explains that at the moment, but `0` is a special case.

Comment: @KirkWoll Thanks for pointing that out, updated.